# how to call Aysnctask in android

Tags: android

I am writing an android application, I use Aysnctask to get the current weather using openWeatherAPI. How could I call the Aysnctask class.

this is the Aysnctask class I wrote:

```
private class getWeather extends AsyncTask<String[], Void, String[]>{

    @Override
    protected String[] doInBackground(String[]... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {

             String Url1="http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat="+currentLatitude+"&lon="+currentLongitude;
             s1=getJson(Url1);



             if(s1!=null){


                 JSONObject jObj1 = new JSONObject(s1);

                 Tem=  jObj1.getJSONObject("main").getDouble("temp");
                 pressure=jObj1.getJSONObject("main").getDouble("pressure");
                 humm=jObj1.getJSONObject("main").getDouble("humidity");
                 wind=jObj1.getJSONObject("wind").getDouble("speed");
                 desc=jObj1.getJSONObject("weather").getDouble("description");

                      double tem_c=Tem-273.15;
                    String t=Double.toString(tem_c);
                    results[0]=t;
                    results[1]=Double.toString(pressure);
                    results[2]=Double.toString(humm);
                    results[3]=Double.toString(wind);
                    results[4]=Double.toString(desc);

             }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
        return results;
    }//do in background


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String[] results) {    
        temp.setText(results[0]+"°C");
        hum.setText(results[1]+ "%");
        press.setText(results[2]+ " hPa");
        windSpeed.setText(results[3]+ " mps");
        condDescr.setText(results[4]);

    }



}
```

when I press a button, I want to get the weather of current latitude and longitude, but I don't know how to execute the class

Comment: have you tried my ans.

Comment: @Tamilan yes, the application Crashes with Null Pointer Exception at this line:
temp.setText(results[0]+"°C");

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
getWeather gt= new getWeather();

gt.execute(new String{currentLatitude,currentLongitude});
```

Comment: I want to send current latitude and magnitude. Is this the right way?

gt.execute(new String{currentLatitude,currentLongitude});

Comment: @roa.tah yeah correct i have edited my answer according to your currentLatitude and currentLongitude

Answer (score 0):

Per the android docs [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), which have plenty of examples, you would do:

```
new GetWeather().execute(currentLatitude,currentLongitude);
```

I would personally shy away from holding a reference to it but rather send in what you need or use a listener. Also, please capitalize you classes :)

You access both of them like so in `doInBackGround`

```
String latitutde= params[0];
String longitude = params[1];
```

An example on the docs which you can look at is:

```
new DownloadFilesTask().execute(url1, url2, url3);
```

As you can see, pass however many parameters you need and it'll just be accessible in the array from the first generic parameter you mention. In your case its a `String` array, so you'd send only `Strings`.

Comment: I capitalized it :)
but how could I send latitude and longitude ??

Comment: Exactly how I placed it. I edited the answer after looking at your comment on the other answer.

Comment: the method execute(String[]..) in the type AysncTask<String[],Void,String[]> is not applicable for the arguments (String,String)

Comment: I read the documentation, but I keep getting the error I posted in the previous comment

Comment: Its because your generic is `<String[]...>` Change it to `<String,...>`

Comment: Also, `currentLatitude`, and `currentLongitude` is not defined anywhere. You need to take it out of `params`.

Comment: I get currentLatitude,currentLongitude from onLocationChanged method, what do you mean by taking them out of params

Comment: I don't see a `onLocationChanged` method. But if you send in the longitude and latitude as parameters like my example it should work. Also make sure its like this: `private class getWeather extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String[]>`

Comment: this is not the whole code :)
I changed the class deceleration as you said, but I get Null pointer Exception

Comment: Edit your code above to reflect the changes AND post the first few lines of the error in logcat

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
         new getWeather(currentLatitude,currentLongitude).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, new String[]{null});   
else
         new getWeather(currentLatitude,currentLongitude).execute(new String[]{null});
```

and also add constructor  to your async task

```
        String currentLatitude;
        String currentLongitude;

        //  constructor
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        public getWeather(String currentLatitude, String currentLongitude) {
            this.currentLatitude = currentLatitude;
            this.currentLongitude = currentLongitude;
        }
```

**EDIT 1:**

You cannot parse double to string like this `String t=Double.toString(tem_c);`

you need to parse like below codes.

```
                String t = String.valueOf(tem_c);
                results[0] = t;
                results[1] = String.valueOf(pressure);
                results[2] = String.valueOf(humm);
                results[3] = String.valueOf(wind);
                results[4] = String.valueOf(desc);
```

Comment: the application crashes :(

Comment: @roa.tah where is `temp` where your dicular the temp post that also

Comment: temp is a text view I declared but I didn't write it here

Comment: @roa.tah still getting null pointer post that error code and also check my edit and change it.

Comment: yes, I still getting NPE, I think there is something wrong here :

     results[0]=t;
results[1]=String.valueOf(pressure);
                    results[2]=String.valueOf(humm);
                    results[3]=String.valueOf(wind);
                   results[4]=String.valueOf(desc);

I tried to print each statement in doBackground method, these didn't print

Comment: @roa.tah then print `pressure`, `humm` etc., `System.out.println("pressure : "+pressure);` if that prints post that.

Comment: yes these printed, but result[0],result[1], etc// not printed

Comment: @roa.tah then post that that's may be the issuse.

Comment: you mean  have to make a new question?

Comment: @roa.tah no no i need to that values to see what is the error?